# how to pass list of list values from jsp to servelet

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have one requirement like when user selects multiple rows which indicates computer parts
and clicks submit i have get all selected parts in servlet and then i need to create part object and set properties

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/OneServlet">
        <c:foreach item="part" value="${computer.spareParts}">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="${part.no}"></td>
                <td>${part.no}</td>
                <td>${part.name}</td>
                <td>${part.cost}</td>
                <td>${part.discription}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:foreach>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

one solution is create string using javascript and pass to Servlet and then split string in servlet.

I am not using any frame work and jquery.

Please suggest best way.

Comment: Just a note, your form will probably not work because `action="/OneServlet"` is an absolute path that will not include your project context.

Answer (score 0):

Give same name to all the checkboxes, and in servlet use request.getParameterValues(checkbox_name), which returns you all selected values.

API for your reference
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Comment: if i follow your suggestion, I can only get parts numbers. but I can not get remaining properties of parts.

Comment: But in the above code snippet I see only part no as input type and rest of the properties as just displaying purpose.

Comment: We can still get other details by following below steps, 1) Declare other properties as hidden input types by giving id as name_{partno} and cost_{partno}. 2) And in servlet you loop through partno's and get their details as request.getParameterValues(name_partno) and other properties in similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Give only one name for all the checkboxes in the loop say partNumbers. This will all the selected checkboxes in String array.

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <form action="/OneServlet" method="POST">
            <c:foreach item="part" value="${computer.spareParts}">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="partNumbers"></td>
                    <td>${part.no}</td>
                    <td>${part.name}</td>
                    <td>${part.cost}</td>
                    <td>${part.discription}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:foreach>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Store your spareParts collection as:

```
    request.getSession().setAttribute("list", spareParts);
```

So when you submit this form, you can retrieve the selected spare parts in your oneservlet by request.getParameterValues() method which returns an array of String objects containing all of the values in given request parameter:

```
    public class OneServlet extends HttpServlet{
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{
        String[] partNumbersSelected = request.getParameterValues("partNumbers");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        List spareParts = session.getAttribute("list");
        /*This is pseudo code
        for(spareParts loop){
            for(partNumbersSelected){
                if(partNumberSelected matches spareParts){
                        retrieve part name, cost, description from spareParts
                }
            }
        }   */  
        }
    }
```

Basically in this you will be capturing the selected part numbers and retrieving the rest of details from spareparts collection.

Comment: Thank you,Prasad. It works if there are unique part numbers. But my actual requirement have duplicate part numbers.

Comment: Do you mean it does not work for duplicates? Common - it captures all the checkbox values whether the valuesof checkboxes are duplicates are not. You need to handle it in controller for that logic.

Answer (score 0):

i think one of the best solution is store it in session

in your jsp Page you try it like this..

```
ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
lst.add("test1");
lst.add("test2");
session.setAttribute("list", lst);
```

in your servlet...

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Arraylist lst = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("lst");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

**html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/OneServlet">
        <c:foreach item="part" value="${computer.spareParts}">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="partNo" value="${part.no}"/></td>
                <td>${part.no}</td>
                <td>${part.name}</td>
                <td>${part.cost}</td>
                <td>${part.discription}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:foreach>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**servlet**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{
    String[] partNos = request.getParameterValues("partNo");
    // your logic
}
```